# Cross process COM Marshaler: reduce number of copies for large arrays

Tags: c++, windows, com, marshalling

As simplified case: I need to transfer a VARIANT to another process over the existing COM  interface. I currently use the MIDL-generated marshaller.

The actual transfer is for many values, is part of a time-critical process, and may involve large strings or safearray's (a few MB), thus number of copies made seems relevant.

Since the receiver needs to "keep" the data beyond the function call, at least one copy needs to be made by the marshaler. All signatures I can think of invlove two copies, however:

```
SetValue([in] VARIANT)
GetValue([out] VARIANT *)  // called by receiver
```

In both cases, in my understanding the marshaller makes a cross-process copy that does get destroyed by the marshaller. Since I need to keep the data in the receiver, I need to make a second copy.

I considered "detaching" the data at the receiver:

```
SetValue([in, out] VARIANT *)  
    // receiver detaches value and sets to VT_EMPTY for return
```

But this would also destroy the source.

**Q1:** Is it possible to get the MIDL-generated marshaling code to do only one copy?
**Q2:** Would this be possible with a custom marshaller, and at what cost? (My first looks into that were extremly discouraging)

I am pretty mouch bound to using SAFEARRAY and/or other VARIANT/PROPVARIANT types, and to transfer the whole array.

**[edit]**

Both sides use C++, the interfaces are IUnknown-based, and it needs to work cross-process on a single machine, in the same context.

Comment: The sender (client) calls `SetValue`, the receiver (server) implements it. Is there some detail here you're not providing, such as both the sender and the receiver being clients of another remote object? If you need to transfer between the two entities with such a remote object in the middle, you can use `SetValue([in] IMyArray *)` and `GetValue([out] IMyArray **)` where `IMyArray` then has `GetArray([out] VARIANT *)`. Then, the receiver can ask the sender for the array directly.

Comment: Question 1:  Does this need to be automation-compliant (i.e., can this be called from different languages)?  If so, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Question 2: Does this have to work across machines, or just across processes on a single machine?  If it's just across processes, then the marshaling gets a lot simpler (you don't need to build fancy wire format, etc.).

Comment: @EricBrown: see update, it's IUnknown on a single machine.

Comment: @acelent: The problem - as much as I understand it at least - is that the marshaler needs to make a copy, and there's no way to tell it not to free it. This forces me to have that second copy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say so explicitly, but it seems the problem you are seeking to solve is speed issues.  In any case, **consider using a profiler to identify the bottleneck** if you haven't already done so.

I very much doubt in this case that it is the copying which is taking the time. Rather, it is likely to be the context-switching between processes involved, as you are getting the values one at a time. This means that for each value you retrieve, you have to switch processes to the target of the call, then switch back again.

You could speed this up enormously be making your design less "chatty" when setting or getting multiple values.

Something like this:

```
SetMultipleValues(
[in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* asNames,
[in] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* avValues
)

GetMultipleValues(
[in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* asNames,
[out,retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* pavValues
)
```

I.e. when calling `GetMultipleValues`, pass in an array of 10 names, and receive an array of 10 values in the same order as the names passed in, (or `VT_EMPTY` if the value does not exist).